# How do I put a print statement in mrjob code for debugging purposes?

Tags: python, mrjob

How do I put a debug statement (like print) in reducer or mapper for mrjob. If I try to use print or sys.stderr.write(), I get an error TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that the output handle is open to a binary stream, not a text stream (the difference between `open(filename, 'w')` and `open(filename, 'wb')`. Try

```
sys.stdout.write(message.encode())
```

If the encoding is not your default encoding, you have to add that explicitly (e.g. `message.encoode('utf-8')`).